# Content Field Type Image not auto resizing

Tags: media

I am fairly new to Drupal, I am currently working through Tom Geller's excellent video series on Lynda.com. All is going well, except I am having a problem when trying to set display properties for any content types containing an image field. If I keep the display settings for the image field as the original image then it will display. However if I try to set an image style for example to use as a thumbnail for a teaser, the image does not show. In Chromium there is an empty frame of the correct size but the image does not display. In Firefox only an empty space is shown where the image should appear.
I am running my site on a local Apache server which contains multiple sites, and the issue occurs in all the sites. I have the most recent stable versions of Apache, PHP and mySQL. I have come across other threads on various sites where people have had this issue however their fixes have not worked for me. I'm sure its simple fix but its been bugging me for hours!
Thanks in advance,
Jackson

Comment: Have you verified that the images are being created by checking `public://styles` (`/sites/default/files/styles`)?  If the images are not there, then you might have a permissions problem.  Check `/admin/reports/status` for any directory permission errors.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRyan it was a permissions error. Nothing showed up in the status report but when I checked the permissions of the styles folder through the folder properties dialog the group www-data was set to access only. Changing that to Create and Delete files solved the problem. If you want to add an answer I will accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the images are being created by checking public://styles - `(/sites/default/files/styles) by default`.  If you see that the images are not being created then you might have your folder permissions set up incorrectly.  `/admin/reports/status` might hint at any permissions problems.